# Do people skip the y in contracted hiragana like in kya kyu kyo?

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

Im trying to learn the contracted hiragana pronunciation and I'm having a problem with the y part.for example きゃ is supposed to be pronounced kya but i feel like some people pronounce it like Ka . Should i too pronounce it as ka or are people just pronouncing kya fast. I Also noticed that with し　じ　ち people just skip the y when pronouncing and are even written without y. So my question is should i pronounce the y or skip it? or do i only skip it with し　じ　ち?

Comment: What resources are you using to teach yourself Japanese?  These pronunciations rules for combining various kana should be explained in most books.  Regarding きゃ, when is it that you think it's being pronounced as か?  Perhaps provide an example where you heard this.

Comment: It sounds like you're referring to romaji when you say "and are even written without y". Romaji for learners is designed to elicit close pronunciations from foreigners, so it shouldn't be taken as any kind of factual element of the pronunciation of natives. I would recommend listening to more recordings of natives pronouncing words with きゃ or しゃ or じゃ, and you will hear distinct differences from か or し or じ.

Comment: @Leebo except with しゃ the ゃ is only contributing the vowel sound.  Is there a dialect in which the "y" is still pronounced here?  There seems to be a number of approaches to romaji these days, some going to far to be faithful to the kana spelling rather than the pronunciation and thus obscuring the actually pronunciation.  And perhaps depending on the native language for the OP, perhaps these differences are harder to hear?  Just wondering.

Comment: @A.Ellett If "not pronouncing the y" results in しゃ sounding like some other kana, like さ or something... then I would say the OP should definitely be pronouncing it. The terminology of the question seems muddled though, so there may be some linguistic definition by which "skipping the y" makes sense but still results in the correct pronunciation. I don't know enough about linguistics. きゃ definitely shouldn't sound like か, though, so this seems like a more fundamental problem.

Comment: @A.Ellett so i should pronounce the y with all of them with the exception of し　じ　ち ?

Comment: @A.Ellett unfortunately i have no other resources than YouTube videos. We don't have japanese books in my country. The main video i used for hiragana is this one: https://youtu.be/6p9Il_j0zjc?si=n53hSJLjpk3zYOfr

Comment: @EllhbaOussama would you mind sharing what your native language is? As A.Ellett pointed out, it may affect your ability to hear certain sounds. For pronunciation, you can try a site like Forvo to hear natives saying various words.

Comment: @Leebo my native language is Arabic. With kya i said some because sometimes it was obviously pronounced as kya but maybe the other times they spoke so fast i didn't pick up on it.

Comment: @Leebo could i bother you please to check how is ぎゃ pronounced here https://forvo.com/search/%E3%81%8E%E3%82%83/

Comment: @EllhbaOussama I would describe that as having a "y" sound in it that makes it different from が. That's how it sounds to me.

Comment: It's not about whether you pronounce the "y" or not. The difference is in the consonant itself. It's just that this difference is already clearer with し, じ and ち without ゃ. The consonants in か and き are also different, only not so much as to warrant different IPA signs.

Comment: @Leebo to my ear (IPA incoming), さ is /sä/ and しゃ is /ʃä/. But the point is that, because full-sized や by itself is /jä/, one would naturally expect しゃ to be /ʃjä/ instead. (Well, actually /ʃʲä/, by analogy with the pronunciation difference between 美容院 and 病院.) That's what "the ゃ is only contributing the vowel sound" and "the "y" is [not] still pronounced here" means. "I don't know enough about linguistics." - it's hard to explain otherwise; start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet

Comment: @aguijonazo "The consonants in か and き are also different, only not so much as to warrant different IPA signs." - I can't hear it and haven't seen it attested in literature. Certainly the difference is not analogous to the た/ち(/つ) distinction, since velar sibilants are considered an impossible articulation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - I didn't say き was a sibilant if that's what you are suggesting. It's palatalized compared to か just like し is to さ and ち is to た.

Comment: し and ち are clearly sibilants, and I don't hear the palatalization.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel (As far as you believe in Wikipedia), [シ is palatalized](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A3%E8%93%8B%E5%8C%96). At least the consonant is clearly different from サ, which is why it's written (more often) *shi* instead of *si*.

Comment: As suggested in the comments, the romaji *kya* is just a way to represent the Japanese sound きゃ and does not necessarily mean the sound contains *k*/*y*/*a* consecutively.  The *y* here marks the *k* is palatalized. If you know Cyrillic alphabets, か and きゃ could be transcribed (very roughly) as ка and  кя, respectively.

Comment: @sundowner Well, if Japanese speakers consider that シ is /ɕi/ rather than /ʃi/, that's certainly good enough for me. The romanization `shi` connotes the latter, but that's just the phonemic inventory that English speakers have to work with (and it's difficult as an English speaker to hear the difference). (One of the neat things about linguistics is that there are two totally separate categories of variation in phones: the kind that's actually phonemic, and the kind that you simply need to get right in order to sound native.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postalveolar_consonant , although this article is internally inconsistent in used nomenclature and symbols. Postalveolar consonants can be generally divided into unpalatalized (e.g. [s̠ z̠ ʂ ʐ]), weakly palatalized (technically *palato-alveolar*) (e.g. [ʃ ʒ]) and strongly palatalized (technically *alveolo-palatal*) (e.g. [ɕ ʑ]). Mandarin and Polish have both unpalatalized and strongly palatalized postalveolar consonants, Japanese and Korean have only strongly palatalized ones, while English and French have weakly palatalized ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the youtube video you point to, the pronunciation used is pretty standard.

Generally, when you use the small versions of ゃ, ゅ, ょ, with any of き, に, ひ, び, ぴ, み, or り, the "i" sound is not pronounced, in its place you pronounce "ya", "yu", or "yo" according to ゃ, ゅ, ょ.

However, with し、じ、ち、or ぢ, the "i" sound is again replaced, but the "y" is lost.  Never the less, the pronunciation of the original consonant sound is modified.  So, しゃ is pronounced as "sha", しょ is pronounced as "sho".

Essentially, before ゃ, ゅ, ょ the consonant sounds for し、じ、ち、or ぢ are changed to "sh", "j", "ch", and "j" (though in some dialects ぢ has its own distinct pronunciation).  As the video you linked to explains, ぢ isn't really used except in very specially cases and not generally in combination with ゃ, ゅ, ょ.

You linked to forvo for ぎゃ.  Indeed, they are pronouncing it as "gya".  Some folks might pronounce this "g" as "ng" in the English "sing" (but it seems this pronouncing is falling out of use though it was quite predominant in Kyushu when I lived there).

I am not a linguist.  However, it often seems to me that in certain combinations like きゃ, きゅ, or きょ what's happening is a palatalization of the preceding consonant.  To an English ear, this still seems like saying "ky" but there's a softer touch to the "y".

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you have any recommendations for resources that are free to access?

Comment: @EllhbaOussama Unfortunately, I do not.  There are a lot of resources on youtube, but many assume a moderate degree of fluency and many others start from absolute zero.  The problem is there doesn't seem to be much inbetween these two extremes.

Comment: "However, it often seems to me that in certain combinations like きゃ, きゅ, or きょ what's happening is a palatalization of the preceding consonant." I am at most an amateur, self-studied linguist, but I agree with this assessment. I'm not sure if "softer touch" is how I'd describe it personally. I would say "more blended" or something like that.

Comment: @EllhbaOussama There are useful resources, including sound samples, in English Wikipedia (I do not know about Arabic Wikipedia). E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics) , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_fricative , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_affricate

Comment: @A.Ellett Regarding じ and ぢ, in Kagoshima dialects which preserve historical distinction, じ has fricative [ʑ] (i.e. voiced equivalent of し [ɕ]), while ぢ has affricate [d͡ʑ] (i.e. voiced equivalent of ち [t͡ɕ]). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana

Comment: @Arfrever That's what I feel like I recall hearing when I traveled around Kyuushuu.